# Add line after `<p>` tag using only CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this block of code that will render a column using the post meta attached to a wordpress page. I need to add a line after the content of the `<p>` tag. How I can do this? I've tried using `::after` but without success. I'm not a master with css so any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php if( $post_meta['col-1'][0] ): ?>
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-background p-0" data-bg-url="<?php _e( $col1_image ); ?>">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 p-5" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8)!important;height:100%;">
        <p class="lead text-center pt-5 mt-5"><?php _e( $post_meta['col-1'][0] ); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the question, can you explain a little further what you mean by "add a line after the content"? Do you have an image you can include? Or do you mean that you want some extra space after the `<p>` tag?

Comment: I mean a line after the `<p>` tag content, not a space. Something like this website is doing under the description text that are near the images https://itrecampanili.com/la-famiglia/ . I think that it's an `::after` css rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a CSS pseudo element like ":after".

So here is your HTML, which is basically a p tag:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Non ego tecum iam ita iocabor, ut isdem his de rebus, cum L. Hoc ille tuus non vult omnibusque ex rebus voluptatem quasi mercedem exigit. Quis non odit sordidos, vanos, leves, futtiles?</p>
```

And here is your CSS:

```
p {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

p:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

Be sure to always give to your pseudo-elements:

- *display: block/inline-block;*
- set a width
- set a height
- set a positioning (absolute/relative - top/left/bottom/right)
- *content: "";* (you will use *background-color* to change its appearance)

Here's a working live pen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/pojgePG

Hope this helps!